# Bootstrap V4 collapsible Navbar alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, twitter-bootstrap-4

I got a question about BS4 and the alignment of a collapsible Menu.

Here is the Code I got:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up pull-xs-right"
            data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-content">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs nav-content">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Leagues</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[Basic without](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7SAl.png)

The Problem is, that I want to have the Menu Items (when not collapsed) aligned to the right and when collapsed, to the left side but below the Hamburger Button and the main nav. It worked fine with BS 3.

I've tried it with float-xs-right, but the it still doesn't work properly.

[With float right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnuL0.png)

Kind regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version you're using of Bootstrap 4, the syntax has changed to float-**-right (See [Responsive floats](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/responsive-helpers/#responsive-floats)) as of the current v4.0.0-alpha.5, see this post under [Utilities overhaul](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2016/10/19/bootstrap-4-alpha-5/).

Another issue is when using a Responsive (float) utility against the `navbar-toggler` button, the list items will appear next the the `navbar-brand` instead of below it. As of right now I believe you have to handle this yourself by clearing the float within the correct breakpoint for your collapse.

**Example CSS:**

```
@media (max-width: 574px) {
    .navbar-header:after,
    .navbar-header:before {
        display: table;
        content: " "
    }
    .navbar-header:after {
        clear: both
    }
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
@media (max-width: 574px) {
  .navbar-header:after,
  .navbar-header:before {
    display: table;
    content: " "
  }
  .navbar-header:after {
    clear: both
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BRAND</a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up float-xs-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content" aria-controls="nav-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="nav-content">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav float-sm-right">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">BLOG</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">LOGIN</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">SIGN UP FREE</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Bro. Any idea, why it takes a while till the dropdown is on the right hand side? it starts from the left and moves to the right.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I don't see anything like that in the example I posted.

Comment: I just keep it on the left ;-) Thanks mate